# Chrome extension: message from background.js to content.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from `background.js` to `content.js` using the following code:

**Background**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'method': 'test'});
```

**Content**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.method == 'test')
    console.log('Got message');
});
```

The background message is sent when `background.js` receives a specific message from `popup.js` which occurs on a click event. So the user clicks a button in the popup and a message is sent to background and then to content.

I have a feeling my problem is something to do with the fact that when the button is clicked in the popup (which is a separate tab), the content script does not receive it because it is not the current active tab.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 39):

There are 2 `sendMessage` functions in Chrome API.

- [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) sends a message to *all* open *extension pages* (i.e. background, popup, etc.)
- [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) sends a message to *all* content scripts from the extension *in a given tab* (possibly filtered by frame ID)

So, to send a message TO a content script, you need to use `chrome.tabs`. To send a message FROM a content script (or within the extension pages), you need to use `chrome.runtime`.

The event is `chrome.runtime.onMessage` in both cases.

See [Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for more details.

Comment: This also helped me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952019/chrome-runtime-onmessage-addlistener-not-registering-within-created-tab) when I thought my problems were coming from the other side