# chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener not registering within created tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following script is injected from my background.js when I create a new tab (new tab loads a site, ie Google.com).

```
$(function(){
  //this fires when tab is created and script injected
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({title: window.document.title}, function(){});
  //this fires when clicking on element in created tab
  document.getElementById("Username").addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({someMessageFromLiveSite: 'Clicked in live site!'});
  });

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, _, sendResponse) {
    //this never fires
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({title: 'This is the created tab responding to a msg'}, function(){});
    //code continues...
```

As commented above, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` seems to work fine, as does a vanilla JS event listener, but the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener does not seem to be added/is not responding from messages sent from other parts of the extension (background or other created pages).

Comment: _How_ do you send messages from other pars? `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` won't work.

Comment: ah... I was just using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({someMessageFromMothership: message});` in the background and other places. I've just seen the [long-lived connections docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), which I'll try next

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: message from background.js to content.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766268/chrome-extension-message-from-background-js-to-content-js)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that one, as I can definitely send messages from my content scripts to my background, but cannot create listeners. This title is still applicable to the specific problem. I will be trying to resolve it using the `connect` and `ports` for long running messaging between both and will post the answer here if successful.

Comment: Read my answer to that question carefully. It's not the listener you can't make, it's that you need different functions to send TO content scripts.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was able to send to the specific tab using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` vs `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. I guess this is not necessarily a duplicate, but I was asking the wrong question! It has been a confusing time writing this first CRX. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Xan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768389/1668057), I realized that I was attempting to broadcast a message to all of my created tabs from background using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, but as explained, this does not broadcast and so `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(TAB_ID....` was required in order to get the listener responding on my created content tab.

Whilst the title is technically inaccurate for the problem I was having, it seemed to me the correct symptom, so this answer may still be of help for others.