# Chrome Runtime OnMessage Listener event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`script/contentscript.js`

```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
     alert("hi");
     return true;
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, {hello:"hello"});
```

I'm at a loss. Either `addListener` isn't registering the callback, the callback isn't being fired when a message is sent, or something in between. I've done what I can to limit the possible errors. At one point the `sendMessage` was in my `popup.js` and after hours of trying different variations, I ported it to another computer. When I got desperate enough to put the `sendMessage` in the same file it was a surprise to find `sendMessage` wouldn't work even in the same contentscript!

I've used both runtime and tabs objects as well as every variation of both `sendMessage` and `onMessage.addListener`.

One odd thing is that when on a breakpoint in the content script, I've seen `hasListener` usually return false and `hasListeners` return true after my listener is added.

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
  "16": "images/icon-16.png",
  "128": "images/icon-128.png"
},
  "default_locale": "en",
  "content_scripts":[
{
   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
   "js":["scripts/contentscript.js"]
}
],
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
   "19": "images/icon-19.png",
   "38": "images/icon-38.png"
 },
   "default_title": "pluralsight dl",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
   "options_page": "options.html",
   "permissions":[
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
]
}
```

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work? Both computers are using Version 43.

A popup js message that also doesn't register. Same extension package.

`script\popup.js`

```
'use strict';

console.log('\'Allo \'Allo! Popup');
// File executed, it's ready for the message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, { action: "start"});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sendMessage` *never* fires the event in the same context. Only *other* contexts receive the message.

As for your initial problem, there are 2 forms of `sendMessage`: `runtime.sendMessage` sends messages to extension's own pages (origin `chrome-extension://yourId/`) and `tabs.sendMessage` that sends messages to content scripts. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766268/934239) for more details.

Comment: that definitely makes sense. I have a `popup.js` that also sends a message, I added the `sendMessage` to the contentscript only because this wasn't working originally for debug purposes. Using either tabs or runtime still doesn't fire my event.

Comment: It will not fire an event in the same page.

Comment: Sorry, I added a bit to the end of my question. I meant my popup.js will not fire the event either, regardless of using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`

Comment: Could it be that you [reloaded the extension and did not reload the page with the content script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23895822/934239)?

Comment: Nope, I've been refreshing constantly for debugging purposes. At one time I was using an executeScript function from the popup.js but reverted once I ran into these issues.

Comment: Um, why do you return true? That's actually a special thing in the context of this event listener, meaning "will reply later, wait".

Comment: I was trying to solve the initial issue and ran into some advice somewhere but it really didn't apply, wasn't like it was firing anyways. But I've got it working using `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` like you suggested.

Comment: One question though, at one point I had this working by using executeScript to open my "contentscript" and then send a message to it. At some point it just stopped working. Any clue what may have caused that? No worries if you don't.

Comment: Race condition? Everything is async, you should only try to send the message from the callback of `executeScript`.